# How can I build a deep reinforcement learning model that can be trained with multiple time series datasets

Tags: reinforcement-learning, training, dqn, deep-rl, time-series

I built a DRL model to trade stocks in the financial market but the number of observations is relatively small and I would like to increase it by training the same model with stocks from several different companies. My problem is that I don't know what is the correct way to do this since the price series is a time series. Someone to enlighten me? I have read articles that show that this is possible but none that say how.

Comment: Have a look through [this stored search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22reinforcement+learning%22+%22time+series%22&oq=%22reinforcement+learning%22+%22time+series%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.17703j0j4&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)